# How to apply Named Entity Recognition function to all columns and return column names that meets criteria

Tags: python, nlp

I have the following code I am using to identify if a column type is "GPE" or not, which means that a field contains the name of a Geo-Political Entity.

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

text = [["Canada", 'University of California has great research', "non-location"],["China", 'MIT is at Boston', "non-location"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['text', 'text2', 'text3'])
df['new_col'] = df['text2'].apply(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(x).ents)])
df
```

However, it can only be applied to one column at a time and I am wondering how could I modify it so that it could be applied to all the columns within the data frame and then only return the name of columns that contain more than one "GPE" as the data type.

Desired output (Showing the column 'text' because both rows are GPE) :

```
text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dataset columns, iterate over them and use the same logic to append to new cols to the existing dataset as follows:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
text = [["Canada", 'University of California has great research', "non-location"],["China", 'MIT is at Boston', "non-location"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['text', 'text2', 'text3'])

col_list = df.columns # obtains the columns of the dataframe

for col in col_list:
    df["".join("ent_" + col)] = df[col].apply(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(x).ents)]) # combine the ent_<<col_name>> as the new columns which contain the named entities.
```

From this obtained updated dataframe, a filter can be applied to drop those columns not containing the GPE values.